# Probability of getting a binary sequence of length $M+N$ where first $r$ digits contain $k$ $1$'s

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A binary string containing $M$ $0$'s and $N$ $1$'s (in arbitrary order, where all orderings are equally likely) is sent over a network. What's the probability that the first $r$ bits contain exactly $k$ $1$'s?

My attempt: I'm trying to find the number of strings that contain $k$ $1$'s and $(r-k)$ $0$'s among the first $r$ bits. Assuming the first $r$ digits already have $k$ $1$'s and $(r-k)$ $0$'s, the way to arrange them would be $\frac{r!}{k!\ (r-k)!}$. Corresponding to each of these the remaining digits can be arranged in $\frac{(M+N-r)!}{(N-k)!\ (M-r+k)!}$ ways. The total number of binary strings would thus be
$$\frac{(M+N-r)!\ r!}{(N-k)!\ (M-r+k)!\ k!\ (r-k)!}$$

This can be divided by $\frac{(M+N)!}{M!\ N!}$ to get the answer.

Is the answer correct? And is there an alternative approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is an alternative approach.
Assume we have a bag with $M$ zeros and $N$ ones. the binary string is chosen by taking one of the items in the bag at random and appending it to the string. It is not hard to see that each valid string is generated with proability $\binom{M+N}{N}^{-1}$
So, what's the probability that among the first $r$ bits, we have exactly $k$ ones?
$$p=\frac{N(N-1)...(N-k+1)\bullet M(M-1)...(M-r+k+1)}{(N+M)(N+M-1)...(N+M-r+1)}\bullet \binom{r}{k}=\frac{M! N! (N+M-r)! r!}{(N-k)!(M-r+k)! (N+M)! k! (r-k)!}$$
What do you know, we got the same answer :)